# how to pass data to Tbxml in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tbxml

i am trying to use TBXML, i want to parse xml by sending username and password but dnt how to do it, i have already gone through many tutorials.

```
  -(IBAction)login{
                    NSString *str2=emailtxt.text;
                    NSString *str3=passtxt.text;

                    TBXML * tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.vinipost.com/my_service.asmx/signIn"]];


                    TBXMLElement *rootXMLElement = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

                    if (rootXMLElement)
                    {
                        TBXMLElement * user = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"Table1" parentElement:rootXMLElement];

                        while (user != nil)
                        {

                            TBXMLElement *CountryId = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"usrid" parentElement:user];
                            if (CountryId != nil)
                            {
                                NSLog(@"CountryId :: %@", [TBXML textForElement:CountryId]);
                            }

                            TBXMLElement *CountryName = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"ContctNmbr" parentElement:user];
                            if (CountryName != nil)
                            {
                                NSLog(@"CountryName :: %@", [TBXML textForElement:CountryName]);
                            }

                            user = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"Table1" searchFromElement:user];
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What is the output for your code?

Comment: Posting to a url and parsing a url are different.

Comment: @sanjitshaw -sorry but i want to login with this url by passing username and password, but how to do it

Comment: Fine, but you have to pass parameters to server either using "POST" or "GET". In case of "GET" u can pass parameters with the url but in "POST" u have to pass parameters in body which may be either "XML" or "JSON".

Comment: @VivekSehrawat Thanks. I'll try, but I'd like to know about the url. Are u using soap? I'm asking because it is a .asmx url.

Comment: @sanjitshaw- these web services are made in C# in .net platform using soap

Comment: Why are you digging into TBXML for making http requests. You should be looking into ASIHTTP Request or AFNetworking for making http requests. TBXML is used for parsing xmls that you may get in response to an http request or from some file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your URL to

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.vinipost.com/my_service.asmx/signIn?email=yourEmail&pass=yourPass"];
```

You can set your email and password on runtime by following this link [Operation On String](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2013/03/operation-on-string.html)